# In Verilog, what is the pragma directive to inform a simulator / synthesizer to throw an error for undefined netlists?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Here's a snippet of code to illustrate a problem I run into from time to time.

```
logic my_elegantly_named_signal;

module_declaration foo (
  .port_name(my_elegantly_named_typo)
);
```

I noticed some simulators and synthesizers will go ahead and quite happily make a wire here that isn't hooked up to anything for `my_elegantly_named_typo`. Obviously, a lint rule would solve this sort of issue, and I'm sure I can find something specific for my simulator tool of choice, but is there a way I can indicate at the top of the file that this should throw an error?

I seem to recall seeing something related to  `defualt_netlist?

Comment: If the answer is this is a violation of the spec or the spec provides no such directive for defining the behavior of undeclared identifiers, I'd accept that too.

Comment: I wish the other question was better indexed. Nothing indicated to me that this question was similar to that one, but I'm glad there's an answer somewhere.